# VUE Nuxt Not able to get array for fetched data

Tags: fetch, nuxt.js, vuejs3, reactive

I am trying to do multiple calls to a server and push each response into an array and have the template display the results.

The function, below, successfully fills up allItems array with x number of members, but it is not reactive so the v-for does not work.

I do not understand how to make the allItems array reactive.

```
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <div v-for="r in allItems" :key="r.title">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="col">
          <div v-if="r && r.ticker" class="stockinfo">
            <span class="ttl">Title: </span><br />
            <span class="main-data"> {{ r.title}} </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { StModel, Results } from "~~/composables/StModel";
import { stks } from "~~/composables/stks.json";
const apiKey = "zzzz";
let allItems: Array<StModel>;

const getData = () => {
  stocks.forEach((s) => {
    fetch("https://zzz.com/a?=" + apiKey)
      .then((response) => response.json() as Promise<StModel[]>)
      .then((data) => {
        allItems.push(data);
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the variable to a `ref` it will be reactive, you just need to use `.value`. No changes are needed to template.

Example:

```html
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <div v-for="r in allItems" :key="r.title">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="col">
          <div v-if="r && r.ticker" class="stockinfo">
            <span class="ttl">Title: </span><br />
            <span class="main-data"> {{ r.title}} </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { StModel, Results } from "~~/composables/StModel";
import { stks } from "~~/composables/stks.json";
const apiKey = "zzzz";
const allItems: Ref<StModel[]> = ref([]); // define as empty array in ref

const getData = () => {
  stocks.forEach((s) => {
    fetch("https://zzz.com/a?=" + apiKey)
      .then((response) => response.json() as Promise<StModel[]>)
      .then((data) => {
        allItems.value.push(data); // then use .value to access array
      });
  });
};
```

as an aside `.then((response) => response.json() as Promise<StModel[]>)` seems like it should be `.then((response) => response.json() as Promise<StModel>)` otherwise the next `then` should be looping through the response (`data`)